# SQLAlchemy core select from join tables in a (0..1) one to one relationship raises Ambigous Name InvalidRequestError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm defining two tables using SQLAlchemy core (version 1.13.12) that must have a one to one (0..1) relationship:

```
things = sa.Table(
    "things",
    metadata,
    sa.Column("sid", sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column("info", sa.String)
)

thingsextra = sa.Table(
    "thingsextra",
    metadata,
    sa.Column("sid", sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey(things.c.sid), primary_key=True),
    sa.Column("moreinfo", sa.String)

fullthings = sa.join(things, thingsextra, isouter=True)
```

I have inserted a single item in "things" table, but not in "thingsextra". Then I'm trying to do a select of the left outer join:

```
query = fullthings.select().where(things.c.sid == sid)
result = conn.execute(query).fetchone()
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Ambiguous column name 'sid' in result set column descriptions
```

It looks like it is not understanding the defined ForeignKey as the same thing, but I do not know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reported error does not occur when executing the query (the query itself it's OK) but when trying to access `sid` column on the result:

```py
>>> result.sid
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Ambiguous column name 'sid' in result set column descriptions
```

The reason is that your SELECT contains two columns with the same `sid` name, one coming from `things` table and the other coming from `thingsextra` as you have joined them. You can check it by showing the `result.keys()`

```py
>>> result.keys()
['sid', 'info', 'sid', 'moreinfo']
```

As column `sid` on `thingsextra` is a foreign key from `sid` on `things` you can remove this column from your SELECT so it only contains one `sid` column. You can do so by selecting the columns you need on your query using `with_only_columns`

```py
>>> query = fullthings.select().with_only_columns([things.c.sid, things.c.info, thingsextra.c.moreinfo]).where(things.c.sid == 1)
>>> result = connection.execute(query).fetchone()
>>> result.keys()                                                                                                                                                                                      
['sid', 'info', 'moreinfo']
>>> result.sid                                                                                                                                                                                         
1
```